# Killing svchost when it becomes too big and clogs up my system

Tags: c#, memory-management, memory-leaks, process

I have a system that I use to run thousands of tests at a time. Over time, this system crashes because of a memory leak. To fix the issue, I'm working on an updated version of the testing infrastructure. This version will dispose of unmanaged resources in a timely fashion. The current version is ten years old and wasn't really coded too well to begin with.

Until I have the time to implement the hundreds of changes that I will need to implement and test, I have found a band-aid. As the system runs, a particular svchost process grows and grows until the system issues an Out Of Memory exception. My solution, which has worked for a week straight now, has been to add some code that terminates any svchost process which grows too large. This has the effect of releasing all of the OS handles issued by unmanaged resources, and it hasn't caused any other problems so far.

My question is - why is this sort of solution frowned upon? If I've gotten it to work on thousands of tests for a week straight, should it be safe for the short term while I work on a real solution to the problem? I realize that it isn't a proper fix because it's treating the symptom rather than the disease, so I'm asking specifically what can go wrong with this method and why this method is frowned upon.

So far, whenever I kill the bloated svchost process, the other svchost processes pick up the slack. Anything OS-specific and required is respawned or passed off to other svchost processes before the largest svchost process is fully terminated. The only thing that is ever really permanently killed is a bundle containing handles emerging from my testing infrastructure programs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after hundreds of thousands of iterations of tests, my solution works almost all of the time. There are a few edge cases that I still need to address, but it works. Multiple svchost processes can exist at any given time, and they can all hold threads for different services. Killing one svchost process is "safe" as long as you're killing the right now.

In my case, over time one svchost process in particular would grow and grow and grow. Once it got to a certain size, I'd kill it and the system would continue running as normal. This is because IF that specific svchost process had any crucial or critical services running inside of it, the OS knows how to port them over to another svchost process before anything is killed. The end result is that you only force-kill what needs to go anyway. This has worked flawlessly for me for many iterations across different machines while running different tests. More data needs to be gathered, but it works AT LEAST FOR THE SHORT TERM. I realize that the proper solution is to go through the entire codebase and dispose of resources properly...but when you're an intern, and when the codebase is large enough that it'd take forever to refactor the code this way...and when it's several .NET memory leaks that are hard to track...it strikes me as okay to break the "rules" and implement a solution such as this one. It's meant to enable us to get data from many iterations of executions while I work on the better solution.